# An End-to-End Secure Mail System

Tags: networking, end-to-end

I am working on research about "**An End-to-End Secure Mail System**". and that is so important for my degrees in college.
I think I did not get that the right way.
I search in the internet but I found no thing useful. maybe I did it the wrong way!

what does that title exactly mean and where I could find any think about it.

anyone can help?

Comment: Is this really the given topic? An e-Mail system can‘t be end to end encrypted. It can have transport encryption like SSL or TLS - both are relying on certificates. End to end would be between the sender and receiver - thus it will be client software based an not server (e-Mail system) based.

Comment: that is what make me confused but unfortunately is the given topic. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End-to-end email encryption is a method of transmitting data where only the sender and receiver can read email messages. With end-to-end email encryption, the data is encrypted on the sender's system. 
What is not end-to-end email encryption?SSL/TLSSMTP over TLS (STARTTLS).
So the main advantage of End to End Secure Mail System is security, that where you should focus on security of the system and transaction. key topic in your research should be internet privacy

Comment: i thought that. i found some thing similar in this link https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5cb0/9565a2939d8e461a07f2f78733fbaf7576f4.pdf
 but I am not specialized and I could not determine if it is exactly what I need.
and i would like to know what the practical field with that (i mean some codes to work with, some apps or programs..) and thanks alot

Comment: if you are a little Good in Programming, C# should be able to do the job